# database design suggesion

Tags: mysql, database-design

am going to start new travel site, 
I want some advise from guru's regarding database design ,
Things coming to picture are,
**Book taxi online** ,
This is the core idea, 
So i like to implement lot of jquery,ajax stuff in my site ,

Main thing site must run veryt fast,safe,security,
In mysql , which typw shall i use,
MYISAM OR INNODB

Which is best type for ajax works, fast,safe ,secure ,performance view .

This is my demo site, 
Just look this site, 
i implemented some ajax stuff here, 
[my-url](http://qa.ukatn.com/005/quickquote-diversion-v2/)

In this site please choose the postcode in the taxifrom tab,

It ask you value please enter, just enter nw7 , See How long it will take for response,some time no response and system goes to hang or idle mode,

Also please look the diversion , select **No** diversion, 
There you will list of textbox, enter the nw3 then hit the search icon ,
See after 80seconds only , you will get response from DB,
See this too bad response ...

This is DB , my Database type if myisam ,no idexing , no fulltext and nothing...no constraints, So please advise me , which database type i choose,

Myisam or innodb,

Thanks
Bharanikumar

Comment: You have at least two questions in your text, but what you really want to know is how to make the query really quick, right? Have you factored in the AJAX call when you measure the response time? First your browser has to respond; your browser asks your webserver; your webserver queries the DB. Are you sure that the last step is the slowest, perhaps your webserver is the real culprit?

Comment: webserver means talking about my hosting....

Answer (score 1):

Database performance of the InnoDB is not necessary faster than the MyIsam engine. Most important difference between them is that InnoDB is transactional and offers referential integrity.

Before looking at different database engines I would start by checking if I have the right indexes on all the necessary columns. Good candidates are all columns in you’re “join”, “where”, “order by” clauses.

Answer (score 0):

before you worry about the differences between MYISAM or INNODB, you need to have your tables layed out properly and having proper indexes!  From there, you need to worry about constructing proper queries that will use the indexes.  Your question gives no details on your table design, but you do say:

> This is DB , my Database type if
>   myisam ,no idexing , no fulltext and
>   nothing...no constraints, So please
>   advise me , which database type i
>   choose,

the `no idexing` and `no constraints` are a big mistake. I'd recommend that you create a new question where you describe the data you need in the database and ask for the best schema to store it, and then go from there.